# How to show detail from .where method rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new with rails and I am trying to show some details using .where method like below:

In the controller method:

```
def detail
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@panier= Panier.where(user_id: current_user, book_id: @book.id).limit(1)

end
```

and in detail.html.erb:

```
<%= @panier.book_id %> | <%= @panier.price %> | <%= link_to 'acheter' , @panier.paypal_url(paniers_path) %>
```

but i got this error:

> undefined method `book_id'

Comment: i found it, I have to use map method.Thanks any way

Comment: Post your own answer then.